# How do I check if the current buffer has a treesit parser?

Tags: tree-sitter

Starting with Emacs 29, we've got native TreeSitter support using `treesit`. My question is: how do I know I can use `treesit-*` functions in the current buffer? The feature check only checks if *Emacs itself* has been compiled with treesit-support. Here's what happens when you ask `*scratch*` whether it has treesit enabled:

```
major-mode ; ⇒ lisp-interaction-mode
(treesit-available-p) ; ⇒ t
```

My current workaround is to check if the treesit language at point is defined:

```
(defun treesit-enabled-p ()
  "Checks if the current buffer has a treesit parser."
  (and (fboundp 'treesit-available-p)
       (treesit-available-p)
       (treesit-language-at (point))))
```

This yields the correct truth conditions, but it doesn't seem terribly idiomatic to query the language at point. Is there a better way?

Comment: Feels a bit like a xy-question, what are you trying to accomplish once you know you can use `treesit-*` functions? Technically you can always use those functions. For example, you can just call `(treesit-node-at (point))`, and it will return the syntax node if the major modes has setup the parser, etc; if there's not a parser in the buffer, the function simply returns nil.

Comment: Well, use those `treesit-*` functions! And fall back to using something else otherwise. I can use any of the treesit-functions (that don't throw errors) to accomplish that, but there doesn't seem to be a "canonical" way.

Comment: The most "canonical" would be to check `(treesit-parser-list)` and see if it's empty. Or you can define a function that uses tree-sitter and call it first, if it returns nil, try the fallback, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to check if treesit is used at point (I'm using polymode):

```lisp
(defun treesit-show-parser-used-at-point ()
  "Shows treesit parser used at point."
  (interactive)
  (if (and (fboundp 'treesit-available-p)
           (treesit-available-p))
      (message (format "%s" (treesit-language-at (point))))
    (message "treesit is not available")
  )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

From the information [here](https://emacs-tree-sitter.github.io/getting-started/), I would guess that

```lisp
(alist-get major-mode tree-sitter-major-mode-language-alist)
```

should do the trick.

That list is customizable, so, if there existed an entry for 'emacs-lisp-mode' then I guess you could also add `lisp-interaction-mode` to the list. However, I don't see emacs-lisp included as a tree-sitter language name.

Comment: That is different to the integration built into Emacs 29.  See also the notice at https://emacs-tree-sitter.github.io/

Comment: Ah thanks, clearly I missed that. Unfortunately, I am unable to build Emacs with tree-sitter support. I am on Fedora and installed libtree-sitter-devel 0.20.7 (and also tree-sitter-cli 0.20.7), but still Emacs does not detect it when running `.configure`. Luckily, I am not in a hurry to test it...

Comment: I should've perhaps made more explicit that the first example serves to show that `treesit-available-p` is `t` *even though* the current major mode is `lisp-interaction-mode`, which is not a treesit buffer (and probably never going to be)